# Why does this vanilla js function return different results in d3v3 and d3v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a MWE based on some templates going from v3 to v4 of the amazing d3.js.

The data is in csv file, both examples load the same file (its clean):

```
day,movie1,movie2,movie3,movie4,movie5,movie6
1,20,8,3,0,0,0
2,18,5,1,13,0,0
3,14,3,1,10,0,0
4,7,3,0,5,27,15
5,4,3,0,2,20,14
6,3,1,0,0,10,13
7,2,0,0,0,8,12
8,0,0,0,0,6,11
9,0,0,0,0,3,9
10,0,0,0,0,1,8
```

here is MWE in question:

```
d3.csv("../data/source/movies.csv", function (error, data) {
dataViz(data)});

function dataViz(incData) {
expData = incData;
stackData =[];    

for (x in incData[0]) {
    if (x != "day") {
        var newMovieObject = {
            name: x, values:[]
        };             
        for (y in incData) {
            newMovieObject
            .values
             .push({
                x: parseInt(incData[y][ "day"]), 
                y: parseInt(incData[y][x])
            })
        }
        stackData
        .push(newMovieObject);
    }}}
```

Now in v3 the `stackData` array has 6 objects with **10** values each e.g.:

```
{name: "movie1" values:[
  {x: 1, y:20} //0
  ... 
  {x:10, y:0} //9
]
…

}
```

In v4 for however I get an array with 6 objects with **11** values each, the last one annoyingly being:

```
{name: "movie1" values:[
  {x: 1, y:20} //0
  ... 
  {x:10, y:0} //9
  {x: NaN, y: NaN} //10 *ouch*
]
…

}
```

As a js noob, I don't understand why this vanilla JS function returns different results, and what to do about it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this difference is that D3 v4.x creates an additional property named `columns` to the `data` array when it parses the CSV (look at [the documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/README.md#d3-dsv)).

So, for instance, given your data:

```
day,movie1,movie2,movie3,movie4,movie5,movie6
1,20,8,3,0,0,0
2,18,5,1,13,0,0
...
```

D3 creates, after the "normal" objects, this additional object (technically speaking, an additional *property* to the array):

```
columns: ["day", "movie", "movie2", "movie3", "movie4", "movie5", "movie6"]
```

Which you can call using `data.columns`.

The problem you're facing right now is that when you use a `for...in` loop you end up iterating this property as well, getting a lot of NaN.

Solution: you can simply avoid iterating over `columns` or, if you don't need it, you can remove it from your data. There are several ways for removing an property from an array in JavaScript, the simpler way being this:

```
delete incData.columns;
```

To check this `columns` property, simply `console.log(data)` using D3 v3 and v4, comparing the results.

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo removing the columns like you suggested solves the problem. If I understand you correctly I would have to modify every function that calls on the data to stop iterating over the columns property. That would be a lot of work. Is there a best practice for placing the `delete` statement. I m now calling it at the top of the 'datavic(incData)' signatory.

Comment: If you are not using this `columns`, you can simply do a `delete data.columns` just after getting the data in the `d3.csv` function.