# d3.tsv/d3.csv columns in accessor (row) function

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Consider the following tsv file:

```
Code    k1  k2
pf_1    0.2 0.3
pf_2    0.3 0.7
pf_3    0.2 0.4
pf_4    0.1 0.6
pf_5    0.8 0.9
```

I 've been trying to understand how the following code works but haven't found a clear answer:

```
d3.tsv("test.tsv") 
    .row(function(d, i, columns){ d.total = columns.length; return d;})
    .get(function(d){ console.log(d);});
```

The specific questions I have are the following:

- What is the underlying parse function that maps the third (columns) argument to the column names in the accessor (row) function?
- Why do I need the row iterator (i) argument in the accessor function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the underlying parse function that maps the third (columns) argument to the column names in the accessor (row) function?

The accessor function, also known as the [row conversion function](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parseRows), is a function invoked for each row, and it takes 3 arguments (which will answer your second question further down):

- The first argument is the *row*
- The second argument is the *index*, starting at zero
- The third argument is the *column names* array

This third argument is interesting, and it was introduced in D3 v4.x. I believe that it answers your first question:

When you load a CSV (or a TSV), `d3.csv` (or `d3.tsv`) creates an *array property* with the headers, named `columns` (take care with loops like a *for...in* loop, because [it will include that property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306815/why-does-this-vanilla-js-function-return-different-results-in-d3v3-and-d3v4)) . In the case of your example, it is:

```
columns: ["Code", "k1", "k2"]
```

And it lead us to your second question:

> Why do I need the row iterator (i) argument in the accessor function?

You don't. The thing is that this piece of code uses the *third* argument, which is the `columns` property, and for being able to use the third argument we have to supply the two arguments that come before it, even if we don't use them:

```
.row(function(d, i, columns){ d.total = columns.length; return d;}) 
//3rd argument---------^
```

There is a convention in JavaScript, not very famous I reckon, that an unused parameter should be named as an underscore (`_`). In that case, this function would be:

```
.row(function(d, _, columns){ d.total = columns.length; return d;}) 
//not used-------^
```

So, what that code does is getting the value of `columns.length`, which is 3, and creating a new property to each object:

```
d.total = columns.length; return d;
```

So, the objects will end up like this:

```
{Code: "pf_1", k1: "0.2", k2: "0.3", total: 3}
```

With the new property `total`.